# Alto uso de la CPU en Visual Studio 2013 e IIS

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013

Cuando usamos Visual Studio 2013 para el desarrollo web, experimentamos los siguientes problemas durante la depuración:

- La aplicación web tarda mucho tiempo en cargar
- Los scripts del cliente tardan mucho tiempo en cargar
- El uso de la CPU por el proceso de trabajo de IIS aumenta enormemente durante la depuración de la aplicación

Cambiar a IIS local no resuelve estos problemas.

**¿Que está pasando aqui?**

Answer (score 2):

Deacuerdo a este sitio https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T102322

La característica **Browser Link** fue agregada en VS 2013. Esto proporciona el intercambio dinámico entre el IDE y cualquier navegador abierto en la máquina. Con la ayuda de esta función, se pueden probar los cambios en la página en los diferentes navegadores sobre la marcha, inspeccionar objetos HTML, etc. Sin embargo, el uso de esta característica puede causar los problemas mencionados en la pregunta durante el proceso de depuración.

Por lo tanto una solución común es **desabilitar** el Browser Link en Visual Studio:

[image]